# NestJS add @Query params to every endpoint

Tags: nestjs

I'm using NestJS to build an API REST. I have several endpoints and each one must have two @Query() params.
My question is: there's a way to assign or create this params without adding on each endpoint individually?

Comment: Do your endpoints have the same query params?

Comment: All my endpoints have these two endpoints. Others may have more, but these two should always be.

Comment: You could create a middleware and apply it to context the specific data u might need from query params.